# Could not push to gitlab using `git lfs push` command

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I track several files in my project using `git lfs`. After that I `add` and `commit` them successfully. But pushing files to gitlab server using `git lfs push origin develop --all` command got the following error.

`batch response: Access forbidden. Check your access level.`

**Server configuration**: Version of gitlab server is `v9.4.3`. I enabled `git lfs` by changing `gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = ture` in the `gitlab.rb` file. After that I `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart` the server.

**Client**: Version of git is `v2.11.0.windows.1`. Output of `git lfs env` is as follows.

```
git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.8.3; git d2f6752f)
git version 2.11.0.windows.1

Endpoint=http://<ip>:<port>/<group>/<project>.git/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=D:\project
LocalGitDir=D:\project\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=D:\project\.git
LocalMediaDir=D:\project\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=D:\project\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=D:\project\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_LFS_PATH=D:\Program Files\Git LFS
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

**PS:** I also run `git config lfs.batch true` command but nothing changed. Total size of files are about `12GB`. Both `https` and `http` protocols for url checked. Connection/Response time of the server is as default. I am authorized to push `origin/develop`. Moreover, `git lfs fetch` command works successfully(i.e without access forbidden error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to all of above steps to enable lfs for a repository, there is an small **LFS** option between many options located at: *repository page* -> *setting* -> *general* which must enable it.

Answer (score 0):

it was the last item in the repository pages so you have to scroll down till bottom to turn it on.